I want to know how to find anchor test script source code
i want to know how to find the method source code in testing javascript, for example the method "program.account.multisig.createInstruction()"source code in follow code:
require('dotenv').config(); 
    const anchor = require("@coral-xyz/anchor");
    const { assert } = require("chai");
    
    describe("multisig", () => {   // Configure the client to use the local cluster.   anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
    
      const program = anchor.workspace.Multisig;
    
      it("Tests the multisig programs", async () => {
        const multisig = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        const [multisigSigner, nonce] =
          await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [multisig.publicKey.toBuffer()],
            program.programId
          );
        const multisigSize = 200; // Big enough.
    
        const ownerA = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        const ownerB = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        const ownerC = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        const ownerD = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        const owners = [ownerA.publicKey, ownerB.publicKey, ownerC.publicKey];
    
        const threshold = new anchor.BN(2);
        await program.rpc.createMultisig(owners, threshold, nonce, {
          accounts: {
            multisig: multisig.publicKey,
            rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
          },
          instructions: [
            await program.account.multisig.createInstruction(
              multisig,
              multisigSize
            ),
          ],
          signers: [multisig],
        });
    
        let multisigAccount = await program.account.multisig.fetch(
          multisig.publicKey
        );
    
        assert.strictEqual(multisigAccount.nonce, nonce);
        assert.isTrue(multisigAccount.threshold.eq(new anchor.BN(2)));
        assert.deepEqual(multisigAccount.owners, owners);
    
        const pid = program.programId;
        const accounts = [
          {
            pubkey: multisig.publicKey,
            isWritable: true,
            isSigner: false,
          },
          {
            pubkey: multisigSigner,
            isWritable: false,
            isSigner: true,
          },
        ];
        const newOwners = [ownerA.publicKey, ownerB.publicKey, ownerD.publicKey];
        const data = program.coder.instruction.encode("setOwners", {
          owners: newOwners,
        });
        console.log(Buffer.from(data).toString('hex'));
    
        const transaction = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        const txSize = 1000; // Big enough, cuz I'm lazy.
        await program.rpc.createTransaction(pid, accounts, data, {
          accounts: {
            multisig: multisig.publicKey,
            transaction: transaction.publicKey,
            proposer: ownerA.publicKey,
            rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
          },
          instructions: [
            await program.account.transaction.createInstruction(
              transaction,
              txSize
            ),
          ],
          signers: [transaction, ownerA],
        });
    
        const txAccount = await program.account.transaction.fetch(
          transaction.publicKey
        );
    
        assert.isTrue(txAccount.programId.equals(pid));
        assert.deepEqual(txAccount.accounts, accounts);
        assert.deepEqual(txAccount.data, data);
        assert.isTrue(txAccount.multisig.equals(multisig.publicKey));
        assert.strictEqual(txAccount.didExecute, false);
    
        // Other owner approves transaction.
        await program.rpc.approve({
          accounts: {
            multisig: multisig.publicKey,
            transaction: transaction.publicKey,
            owner: ownerB.publicKey,
          },
          signers: [ownerB],
        })
    
        // Now that we've reached the threshold, send the transaction.
        await program.rpc.executeTransaction({
          accounts: {
            multisig: multisig.publicKey,
            multisigSigner,
            transaction: transaction.publicKey,
          },
          remainingAccounts: program.instruction.setOwners
            .accounts({
              multisig: multisig.publicKey,
              multisigSigner,
            })
            // Change the signer status on the vendor signer since it's signed by the programs, not the client.
            .map((meta) =>
              meta.pubkey.equals(multisigSigner)
                ? { ...meta, isSigner: false }
                : meta
            )
            .concat({
              pubkey: program.programId,
              isWritable: false,
              isSigner: false,
            }),
        });
    
        multisigAccount = await program.account.multisig.fetch(multisig.publicKey);
    
        assert.strictEqual(multisigAccount.nonce, nonce);
        assert.isTrue(multisigAccount.threshold.eq(new anchor.BN(2)));
        assert.deepEqual(multisigAccount.owners, newOwners);   }); });


could you add more details to your question?

i have update the whole code, in the code, i want to find the js source code call method, how can i find the program.rpc.createTransaction() method :
const program = anchor.workspace.Multisig; const data = program.coder.instruction.encode("setOwners", {
owners: newOwners,
});program.rpc.createTransaction()
